# Making shift up into shift left in 2048 game

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

So I have some code to shift up a board of numbers in a 2048 game:

```
data = [0, 2, 4, 8, 0, 2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0]

def drawBoard(): # Making the board into a 2d array
    count = 0
    for i in range(16):
        print(data[i], end = ' ')
        count += 1
        if count == 4:
            print("")
            count = 0
print(drawBoard())

for col in range(4): #Loop to shift numbers up
    count = 0
    for row in range(4): # read loop
        if data[row*4+col] != 0:
            data[count*4+col] = data[row*4+col]
            count += 1
    for row in range(count, 4):
        data[row*4+col] = 0

print(drawBoard())
```

This basically takes data, makes it into a 4 x 4 board and shifts all the non zero numbers up.
Non Shifted Board:

```
2 2 4 8
0 2 8 0
0 0 0 2
4 2 2 0
```

Shifted Board:

```
2 2 4 8
4 2 8 2
0 2 2 0
0 0 0 0
```

Is there a way using the same format as what I commented "loop to shift numbers up" and make this shift up function into a shift left function?

So the board shifted left looks like:

```
2 2 4 8
2 8 0 0 
2 0 0 0 
4 2 2 0
```

Comment: Please review your code. I get `IndentationError` and an additional line `None`. Also, this is apparently `python-3.x` so do not tag with 2.7.

Comment: The None I can't fix but I fixed the indentation error

Comment: `None` is because you print the result of `drawBoard`. You can also fix your tags.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to rotate the row/col reference, and the code will be the same. Immagine that you turn the grid counter clockwise so your first column is the last row and your first row is the first column

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work.